# Custom background of button is not setting properly

Tags: android, css, android-layout, android-selector

Hello I am designing this page in android (style only)
[image].
First 3 buttons has been designed by taking the reference from [this](http://hateum.github.io/AndroidDrawableGenerator/).

But DONATE NOW button which I have designed is become transparent like this
[image]

as well as click event (statepreseed = "true")is also transparent like
[image].

and here is my code of background for DONATE NOW button

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp" />
           <solid android:color="#33e7d283"></solid>
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#00e9ca30"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:radius="0dp"
                />

            <gradient
                android:angle="225"
                android:centerX="23%"
                android:centerColor="#33f4c40e"
                android:startColor="#ffdab605"
                android:endColor="#ffdab605"
                android:type="linear"
                />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

If any one is having the solution.please help

Comment: shaw your xml layout

Comment: For simple way, I think you should use a `*.9.png`(nine patch file). See here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html and here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: why are you giving alpha to center color ??? you should directly give color code `e7d283` rather than `33e7d283`.

Comment: actually its 2 fragments ,one is of left and one is of right having these 4 buttons.I have set that blue background image to the parent activity of these both fragments.

Comment: using proper color-code can give you better output.  Using alpha will create image with transparent background and it will affect your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ARGB instead of RGB. Because of this you are creating image with transparent background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:centerColor="#e7d283"
        android:centerX="23%"
        android:endColor="#ffdab605"
        android:startColor="#ffdab605"
        android:type="linear" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Using `e7d283` or `ffe7d283` color-code instead of `33e7d283` might solve your problem for yellow image background.

Using 33 as alpha means you are giving only 20% opacity to your center color. That is the reason you can see background color in middle of your image.

Comment: @KiranS : Glad I helped

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..
Your button element should look like below.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/angry_btn"

android:text="Button"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30sp"

android:layout_width="270dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
android:shadowColor="#474747"
android:shadowDx="0"
android:shadowDy="0"
android:shadowRadius="3"
/>
```

**ButtonShape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:radius="14dp"
/>
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:centerX="65%"
android:centerColor="#F5FAF9"
android:startColor="#F39C12"
android:endColor="##F39C12"
android:type="linear"
/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```

Output will look like below.

[image: Output]